# Data isn't completely removed from my android app

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-manifest, android-database, android-bundle

I found a very strange bug in my application. The fact is that after deleting the application, logging out of the account and deleting all data, as well as after clearing the data through the system dialog, when I enter the application I get to another account, in fact the previous account that I used.
[image]

If it was a matter of incorrectly clearing shared preferences, then clearing the data by the system would fix it. After all, this function clears all application data. (screen above)
I also tried to change this field in the manifest, but nothing helped

```
android:allowBackup="true"
```

Here is my manifest:

[image]

And this is happened on any devices.

**I will be grateful to you for any ideas or guesses!**

Comment: android:allowBackup="false" allowBackup field should be false.

Comment: @AzeemHaider As I said I have tried this but it still didn't work

Comment: when you say the it uses the previous account do you mean a google account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone. The error was due to the fact that the server remembered the user by device, and not by login and password. That's why I got the wrong user when I cleared app data